# Pentaho 5.0.1 Reports Showing only on specific Computer

Tags: report, reportviewer, pentaho

Something very strange is going on with my pentaho 5.0.1. I develop and publish reports from computerA to the BI-Server. I was able to log in via ComputersB,C,D..etc to run view reports. Everything was working fine for about two weeks. Now the reports do not show on any other computer apart from ComputerA (where I publish the reports from). This is very strange as I have done no specific update in a while. On other pc's the reports try to load but never actually show. The pages remain blank on other pc's but reports show on ComputerA. The biserver is not local and all computerA...Z run on the same network connecting to the remote biserver and so I am clueless as to why exactly this is happening. Have I done anything wrong. I even installed a fresh biserver but still the same issue. The admin account only opens reports on One computer only.  Please let me know if I am not being clear enough. I have never seen any issue this weird .I am totally ??#@##$#$$?

Pentaho.log

```
2014-02-04 07:39:56,005 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/cdf-require-js-cfg.js not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:45:29,661 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/cdf-require-js-cfg.js not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:45:38,475 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:45:40,412 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:45:41,099 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /BTable/resources/lang/messages_en.properties not found in plugin BTable
2014-02-04 07:45:41,354 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /BTable/resources/lang/messages_en-US.properties not found in plugin BTable
2014-02-04 07:45:41,598 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:45:41,863 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_en.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:45:42,109 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_en-US.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:45:44,890 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /waqr/resources/messages/messages_en.properties not found in plugin waqr
2014-02-04 07:45:45,135 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /waqr/resources/messages/messages_en-US.properties not found in plugin waqr
2014-02-04 07:45:48,161 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /jpivot/jpivot/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in plugin jpivot
2014-02-04 07:45:50,477 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /waqr/resources/messages/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in plugin waqr
2014-02-04 07:52:03,670 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/cdf-require-js-cfg.js not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:52:23,086 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] 480b5626-8d71-11e3-ac46-0025903411e7:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Action sequence execution failed
2014-02-04 07:52:23,096 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] 480d03d7-8d71-11e3-ac46-0025903411e7:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Action sequence execution failed
2014-02-04 07:52:23,125 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] 48114998-8d71-11e3-ac46-0025903411e7:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Action sequence execution failed
2014-02-04 07:52:28,620 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/cdf-require-js-cfg.js not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:52:50,212 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/cdf-require-js-cfg.js not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:52:51,286 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:52:52,402 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:52:59,361 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /BTable/resources/lang/messages_en.properties not found in plugin BTable
2014-02-04 07:52:59,615 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /BTable/resources/lang/messages_en-GB.properties not found in plugin BTable
2014-02-04 07:52:59,911 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:53:00,159 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_en.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:53:00,414 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf-dd/lang/messages_en-GB.properties not found in plugin pentaho-cdf-dd
2014-02-04 07:53:03,203 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /waqr/resources/messages/messages_en.properties not found in plugin waqr
2014-02-04 07:53:03,457 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /waqr/resources/messages/messages_en-GB.properties not found in plugin waqr
2014-02-04 07:53:06,244 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /jpivot/jpivot/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in plugin jpivot
2014-02-04 07:53:08,637 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /waqr/resources/messages/messages_supported_languages.properties not found in plugin waqr
2014-02-04 07:58:10,440 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/cdf.css not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:58:10,453 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/jquery.tooltip.css not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:58:10,672 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/jquery.jdMenu.css not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:58:10,747 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/jquery.jdMenu.slate.css not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:58:10,765 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/jquery-impromptu.css not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
2014-02-04 07:58:11,234 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet] GenericServlet.ERROR_0004 - Resource /pentaho-cdf/js/cdf-require-js-cfg.js not found in plugin pentaho-cdf
```

Catalina

```
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:51 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, sparkl.api, of type pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:51 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.16 11/28/2012 03:18 PM'
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.version(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.reload(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders) throws org.dom4j.DocumentException,java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.status(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders) throws org.dom4j.DocumentException,java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.genericEndpointGet(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders) throws java.lang.Exception, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.defaultElement(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.getSitemapJson(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.listDataAccessTypes(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.reloadPluginsGet() throws java.lang.Exception, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.refreshGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders) throws org.dom4j.DocumentException,java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cpk.CpkApi.elementsList(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, datasources, of type pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.DatasourcesApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, wcdf.editor, of type pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.EditorApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, olap, of type pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.OlapApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, plugins, of type pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.PluginsApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, renderer, of type pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.RenderApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, resourcesapi, of type pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.ResourcesApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, syncronizer, of type pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.SyncronizerApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, version, of type pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.VersionApi as a root resource class
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:52 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.16 11/28/2012 03:18 PM'
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:53 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.OlapApi.getCubeStructure(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,org.json.JSONException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.OlapApi.getLevelMembersStructure(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,org.json.JSONException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.OlapApi.getPaginatedLevelMembers(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,long,long,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,org.json.JSONException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.OlapApi.getCubes(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,org.json.JSONException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.RenderApi.refresh() throws java.lang.Exception, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.ResourcesApi.getResource(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.ResourcesApi.res(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.ResourcesApi.getImage(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.ResourcesApi.getCssResource(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.ResourcesApi.getJsResource(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.ResourcesApi.getUntypedResource(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.SyncronizerApi.syncStyles(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.DashboardDesignerException, MUST return a non-void type.
  WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public void pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.VersionApi.checkVersion(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException, MUST return a non-void type.
Feb 04, 2014 7:40:53 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
```

Comment: would u mind copying your pentaho log for us here?

Comment: Same result deploying on Tomcat 7